# How to create multiple Tooltips?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i create multiple tooltips for multiples class?

https://jsfiddle.net/6v1fbrk9/

```
<img src="http://animekompi.web.id/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/68839-128x200.jpg"/>

<span id="tooltip-span">

    <img class="hidden" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RPZhwHLprkw/WOtXJpHaQ6I/AAAAAAAAE-M/SXjdESQrlZ4FQzWWwrfoSJ9-UWJ4jxxlQCLcB/s1600/q.png" />
</span>
```

Comment: I don't follow, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to multiply that image with other tooltips.

Comment: So you want multiple tooltips on one image, or multiple images with one tooltip?

Comment: Multiple images with one tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to select each of your "tooltip-able" links, loop over them and bind mouseover event to every tooltip content. Also don't use duplicated ids, use classes. I fixed HTML and CSS a little (add z-index).

Something like this will work:

```js
var tooltips = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip'))

tooltips.forEach(function(tooltip) {
  var tooltipSpan = tooltip.querySelector('.tooltip-content');

  tooltip.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;
    tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
  }
})
```

```css
.tooltip {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

a.tooltip .tooltip-content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}

a.tooltip:hover .tooltip-content {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img.hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
  <img src="http://animekompi.web.id/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/68839-128x200.jpg" />
  <span class="tooltip-content">
    <img class="hidden" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RPZhwHLprkw/WOtXJpHaQ6I/AAAAAAAAE-M/SXjdESQrlZ4FQzWWwrfoSJ9-UWJ4jxxlQCLcB/s1600/q.png" />
  </span>
</a>

<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
  <img src="http://animekompi.web.id/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/68839-128x200.jpg" />
  <span class="tooltip-content">
    <img class="hidden" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RPZhwHLprkw/WOtXJpHaQ6I/AAAAAAAAE-M/SXjdESQrlZ4FQzWWwrfoSJ9-UWJ4jxxlQCLcB/s1600/q.png" />
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Wow. You are great. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Question is unclear.

Are you trying to put multiple tooltips for a single image?

If that's the case,You could use image-map or put divs with `background: transparent` at the locations you want the tooltips, and then using the tooltips on it.

[Some help from W3 with map](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Hope this works for you.